# Google Sheets select, count, limit

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

In a Google Sheets document, I've got a column which contains multiple values.
I want to get the first 20 values by count, and then group the count of the others.

I've got this working code for now:

```
=QUERY(B2:B165,"select B, count(B) group by B order by count(B) desc limit 20 label B 'Pubblication venue'")
```

This will get me how many times a value appears in the column, and limit the results to 20. Now I need the count of the other results (which are ~100).

Let me explain by example. With my code I'm able to get the count of A, B and C. Now I want the count of others.

```
+-------+----+
| A     | 5  |
+-------+----+
| B     | 2  |
+-------+----+
| C     | 4  |
+-------+----+
| Other | 90 |
+-------+----+
```

Comment: I can't for privacy reasons

Comment: you want to count other counts or others itself?

Comment: I want to count every element excluded by the limit clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
={QUERY(B2:B165, 
 "select B, count(B) 
  where B is not null
  group by B 
  order by count(B) desc 
  limit 20 
  label B 'Pubblication venue'", 0); 
 {"Other", COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY(QUERY(B2:B165, 
 "select B, count(B) 
  where B is not null
  group by B 
  order by count(B) desc 
  offset 20
  label count(B)''", 0), 
  "select Col1", 0)))}}
```

[image: 0]

### _____________________________________________________________

```
={QUERY(B2:B165, 
 "select B, count(B) 
  where B is not null
  group by B 
  order by count(B) desc 
  limit 20 
  label B 'Pubblication venue'", 0); 
 {"Other", SUM(IFERROR(QUERY(QUERY(B2:B165, 
 "select B, count(B) 
  where B is not null
  group by B 
  order by count(B) desc 
  offset 20
  label count(B)''", 0), 
  "select Col2", 0)))}}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and it works like a charm. Thank you.